# swiftmailer Config

Tags: php, symfony2, email

Estoy configurando `swiftmailer` en `symfony`, `PHP 5.6.*`, `xampp`

Tengo un problema al momento de realizar pruebas para el envió de los correos, mi configuración para `swiftmailer` es la siguiente:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: ###.###.###.#
mailer_user: docencia@colsan.edu.mx
mailer_password: ---------
mailer_port:###
mailer_encryption:tls
```

Genere un test en Java y funciona perfectamente, no tengo idea de que es lo que sucede

```
String username = "docencia@colsan.edu.mx";
String password = "-----------";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "###.###.###.#"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "###");
```

Es necesario realizar alguna configuración para `xampp` o `symfony`?

Saludos!!

Comment: Hey buddy please change your question in spanish language =)! this is StackOverflow in Spanish =) or your question could be closed  =(...

Comment: Excellente y bienvenido a SO en español!

Comment: Gracias, espero puedan auxiliarme es este problema

Comment: Gracias, pude resolver mi problema por medio de este enlace, espero que ayude este aporte cuando necesiten realizar la configuracion sobre un dominio propio: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604159/phpmailer-not-sending-mails-tls-error

saludos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día.

Por fin he dado con la solución a mi problema, posteo el link para ser de ayuda a alguien mas.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604159/phpmailer-not-sending-mails-tls-error

El problema era que el plugin estaba verificando la conexión por SSL, el link que proporciono hace referencia a PHPMailer, ya que sucede la misma situación.

Aquí les dejo el link para hacer funcionar mediante TLS el plugin de swiftmailer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954863/i-cannot-send-mail-with-swiftmailer-or-phpmailer-from-localhost-using-gmail

Saludos!!

Comment: acepta esta respuesta, así ayudarás al sitio a seguir creciendo